# Deploy macros and ribbon button - Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

We need to deploy macros across our organization, along with a shortcut button up on the ribbon, in Outlook 2010.  Right now, the way we're slated to do this is by copying over and overwriting the following files on each machine:

```
VbaProject.OTM
olkexplorer.officeUI
```

However, this will remove any custom macros and customizations by the users to their ribbon.  There shouldn't be ANY custom macros or ribbon customizations, per our security policies... But this is still a very dirty way of doing this task.  Is there a better way to deploy these settings?